# Third Central Moment of the Bernoulli Distribution without Moment Generating Function

Tags: statistics

We can define the third central moment of any distribution as $\mu_3=E[(Y-E[Y])^3]$. Due to the fact that $E[Y]$ in the bernoulli distribution is equal to $p$ because $E[Y]=(p) \cdot 1 + (1-p) \cdot 0=p$, I know what $E[Y]$ is but can't seem to muster the intuition as to what Y would be such that the third central moment is equal to $p(1-p)^3-(1-p)p^3$. Is there an algebraic evaluation that leads to this setup. I have tried various expansions where $Y=1-p,Y=p$. But what value or values does $Y$ take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $Y\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$, then $Y$ takes the value $1$ with probability $p$ and the value $0$ with probability $(1-p)$. As you have noted, this means $E[Y]=1\cdot P(Y=1)+0\cdot P(Y=0)=1\cdot p + 0 \cdot (1-p)= p$.

To calculate $E[(Y-E[Y])^3]$, we can use the fact that for any function $f$, $$E[f(Y)]=\sum_{y} f(y)\cdot P(Y=y)$$
 where the sum is over all values $Y$ can take. Here the function we will use is $f(Y)=(Y-E[Y])^3 = (Y-p)^3$. So we have:
$$E[(Y-E[Y])^3] = (1-p)^3 \cdot P(Y=1) + (0-p)^3 \cdot P(Y=0)= (1-p)^3p-p^3(1-p). $$

Comment: Thank you! This makes a ton of sense. I forgot to realize that the central moment involves expectation and therefore the PMF at discrete values. Cheers!