# Proof of the Third Central Moment of the Binomial Distribution without Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability, expected-value, binomial-distribution

$X$ is the sum of $n$ identical Bernoulli random variables, each with expected value $p$. In other words,  $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ are identical (and independent) Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$, then $X=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}$ and
$$
\mathrm{E}[X]=\mathrm{E}\left[X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}\right]=\mathrm{E}\left[X_{1}\right]+\cdots+\mathrm{E}\left[X_{n}\right]=p+\cdots+p=n p.
$$
The variance is:
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X)=n p(1-p).
$$

**The third central moment,** defined as $$\mu_{3}=\mathrm{E}\left[(X-\mathrm{E}[X])^{3}\right]=n p(1-p)(1-2 p).$$ I saw this result when I was reading Wikipedia. I know the proof process of expectation and variance, but **I don't understand how the result of this third moment is proved?**

Comment: By brute force. You have to expand the cube and compute $EX^{3}$

Comment: Thanks, Kavi. I just edited my question, can it be calculated without MGF?

Comment: @wentingliu yes you do not need to understand what MGF is and calculate expectation as usual

Answer (score 2):

It is not difficult expanding  your expression and using the simple moments to get the final result.

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\mu_3=\mathbb{E}[X^3]-3\mu\mathbb{E}[X^2]+3\mu^2\mathbb{E}[X]-\mu^3
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

The only "difficult" calculation is $\mathbb{E}[X^3]$ but it can be easy  derived using MGF and its properties

EDIT

If you do not want to use MGF, you have to  use the definition of simple moments. In order to get the 3rd simple moment you can factorize $x^3$ in the following way

$$x^3=x(x-1)(x-2)+3x^2-2x$$

Thus (I set $q=1-p$ to simplify the notation)

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X^3] & =\sum_{x=0}^n x(x-1)(x-2)\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^x q^{n-x}+3npq+3n^2p^2-2np\\
& = p^3n(n-1)(n-2)\sum_{x-3=0}^{n-3}\binom{n-3}{x-3}p^{x-3}q^{n-x}+3npq+3n^2p^2-2np\\
& = p^3n(n-1)(n-2)\underbrace{\sum_{y=0}^{n-3}\binom{n-3}{y}p^{y}q^{(n-3)-y}}_{=1}+3npq+3n^2p^2-2np\\
& = p^3n(n-1)(n-2)+3npq+3n^2p^2-2np
\end{align}$$

Now, considering that

$$\mu=\mathbb{E}[X]=np$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=npq+n^2p^2$$

substitute $\mathbb{E}[X^3]$ in (1) and get the desired result

In fact, after some boring calculations, you get

$$\mu_3=\mathbb{E}[X-\mu]^3=np(1+2p^2-3p)=np(1-p)(1-2p)$$

Comment: Hi, tommik~ can it be calculated without MGF? Here is a link that may be useful. [Third Central Moment of the Bernoulli Distribution without Moment Generating Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3421528/third-central-moment-of-the-bernoulli-distribution-without-moment-generating-fun)

Comment: @wenting liu: no, it is not useful because your distribution is binomial, not bernulli. I edited my anwer with all details you requested